# Parsing an XML structure to perform specific operations

Tags: c#, xml

I have to parse a xml structure recursively and perfrom few operations as and when i encounter a particular node.
Which would be a good design pattern or approach for this scenario.

ex:

```
<Start>

<step1>
 // some data
</step1>

<step2>
// some data
</step2>
<step3/>
<step4/>
...

</Start>
```

i want to parse this whole xml and perfrom specific operations for specific steps
For instance step-1 perform addition , for step-2 perform subs and so on

Comment: Please ask a more concrete question. What is the problem exactly? Have you tried anything? What programming language?

Comment: Create a class which can hold the xml data and deserialize xml in to the object, or if you don't want to deserialize, use XPathNavigator.

Answer (score 0):

I would use xml linq like code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication139
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement start = doc.Descendants("Start").FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (XElement element in start.Elements())
            {
                switch (element.Name.LocalName)
                {
                    case "step1" :
                        break;
                    case "step2":
                        break;
                    case "step3":
                        break;
                    case "step4":
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how XSLT works. Just define rules associated with the different elements, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="step1">
  <xsl:value-of select="@arg1 + @arg2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, you need to provide more detail to make this concrete.